# Расположение тэга style

Tags: ajax, html, css

[Тут](http://htmlbook.ru/html/style) написано, что тэг `<style>` должен обязательно быть расположен внутри тэга `<head>`. А как тогда быть с загрузкой страницы (или любой другой информации) через AJAX? Вставлять тэг `<style>` в head программно на javascript? Вообще во всех браузерах, где я тестировал свое приложение, все работает и без этого. Но все-таки хочется узнать как будет сделать правильно.

Comment: А что вас смущает? У меня есть проект, который полностью работает на AJAX, так там даже **description** и **keywords** в мета-тегах меняются AJAX-средствами. Просто не вижу связи между "style в head" и "загрузкой страницы через AJAX"

Comment: @Deonis, а как вы реализовывали это, если не секрет? Просто я вижу два варианта, все данные передавать JSON'ом или прямо в тексте загружаемого html  сделать js-функции (-ию), которые будут вызываться после загрузки (ну например в любом загружаемом документе должна быть функция ajaxLoadComplete которая и будет вызываться после загрузки)? Или есть еще варианты?

Comment: И style, и мета-теги - это все элементы, к которым можно получить доступ по определенным селекторам. У меня, вышеупомянутый проект,  реализован на AJAX+jQuery, соответственно, если мне надо подгрузить те же ключевые слова, то по **complete** я меняю атрибут, как это делал бы с обычным объектом страницы:

    $("meta[name='keywords']").attr("content",data);

Где **data** это переменная, содержащая эти самые ключевые слова

Comment: Вот этот код который вы сейчас написали, у вас где расположен? В контексте основного документа (то что загружает какую-либо страницу) или в коде загружаемой странице? Ведь можно реализовать и так и так. Если первый вариант, то как вы получаете значение для переменной `data`? Вот в чем вопрос...

Comment: Что-то мы на разных языках говорим... У меня всего одна страница - **index.php**, на которой подключен файл **JS**, теперь, по клику пользователя на какую-либо ссылку, подгружается средствами AJAX соответствующий контент, меняются мета-теги и если надо, то и стили для этого раздела. Вот, как бы и всё.

Comment: Видимо, да)) Я хочу у вас вот что узнать. В **Index.php** у вас прописан код загрузки другой страницы, ну например, **Nofelet.php**. В методе jQuery.ajax() можно установить callback-функцию success. В эту функцию передается текст загруженного **Nofelet.php**, ну пусть это будет переменная code. После манипуляций с code в этой функции, нам нужно добавить смену заголовка страницы или ключевых слов. Далеко ходить не будем, добавим туда ваш код:

    $("meta[name='keywords']").attr("content",data);

Внимание, вопрос: как получить data? Надеюсь, понятно объяснил.

Comment: AJAX отправляет запрос отправляется в файл-обработчик(php), вытягиваются нужные данные из базы и формируется ответ таким макаром:

    echo json_encode(array($val_1, $val_2, $val_3, $val_N));

callback-функция success принимает этот массив. Теперь, если в массиве не было ключей, то просто вы должны знать, что **data[0]** - это title страницы, **data[1]** - это ключевые слова, **data[2]** - это, к примеру сам контент и т.д. Теперь остаётся "растыкать" данные в нужные места.

Comment: Теперь понятно все) Спасибо. Я это и хотел у вас узнать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это общая рекомендация, но тег стайл будет работать в любом месте страницы, его можно вставлять туда где вам удобно. Однако все же рекомендуется выносить все стили в цсс файл и не засорять стилями разметку страницы.

Comment: Ну это то понятно, что лучше не засорять, но иногда этого сделать не получается, сами же понимаете...

Comment: А вообще спасибо за ответ. Теперь буду знать наверняка что такое объявление стилей будет работать везде.